# Remove text and lines on specific Rect in a PDF using ABCPdf

Tags: c#, abcpdf

I have an existing PDF which has couple of lines of text and horizontal line in the top of every page. like full file name, date time, and a horizontal line below that. The positions, height and width are same on all pages/pdf files.

I would like to remove those two lines of text and the horizontal line using ABCPdf.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of remove the text (what may not possible), consider place a "white rectangle" hidding it. Then you can "stamp" the doc for a better "cammouflage".

Something like that, for each page:

```
yourDoc.Rect.SetRect ( coordinates ...)
yourDoc.Color.String = "255 255 255"
yourDoc.FillRect()
...
yourDoc.Flatten etc.
```